# Fatal error in excel "Errors where detected while saving filename"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

I have some of excel files and I got an error while saving that says "Errors where detected while saving file name. Microsoft Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make the repairs in a new file, click Continue. To cancel saving the file, click Cancel". I have searched for the problem and I found some solutions that say I have to reinstall office. Do you think this is the right solution?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Office is not the first thing I would do, in fact, it is pretty far down the list of things I would try. If those Excel files are important then your first priority is your data.  You need to save those files before you lose them which means reinstalling Office isn't even an option to consider until later.

I can't leave it unsaid, make sure your actions aren't the problem.  Silly things like trying to save a read only file, using an invalid character in a filename, trying to save to a path that doesn't exist.  If you can rule yourself out, then move on to the next step.

The advice from @vembutech is is valid when a workbook can't be opened so keep that in mind if you succeed in saving the files but can not reopen then.  Sadly, that tool has never worked for me, not once.  I hope you have better results.

You can try saving in different formats like an XLSB.  If it's a simple spreadsheet without a lot if formatting, Pivot Tables, Charts, etc then you can try saving as a CSV.  If it's a macro enabled workbook like an XLSM then try saving without macros as an XLSX. If you succeed, open the newly saved file and try saving in your desired format again.

Try copying your data to a new workbook.  You can export sheets by right clicking on there tab at the bottom, selecting move or copy, and selecting a new workbook as the destination.  I recommend checking the 'Copy' box just as a precaution against.  You could also copy and paste manually.  Now try saving the new workbook.

If you decide to reinstal office then I recommend running diagnosis utilities to rule out a hardware problem like a failing hard drive or faulty RAM but before reinstalling.  If you reinstal with bad hardware then the problem may go away for a day, week, month, year... but it will come back.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From your content I believe that you are having issues in opening certain excel files and not the whole files. This might be due to file corruption issue.

To fix this corruption you can use file--> Open button, and then click Open and Repair.

For various recovery option check [the Microsoft article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repairing-a-corrupted-workbook-e5b49891-dde7-4796-b60a-49b0d2478a62?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score -1):

Well I think you have a issu with your Windows username, for example too long or have any don't liked character.
Try this:
Create a user account in control panel, with administrater privileges, and give this name for the account:
`apple` (if this the problem, must be work the save, becouse not have any unwanted character).
I also suggest for you, save as in this  this name:
`apple`
And if this dident work:
Crtl+a, crtl+C, create a new file in name of `tea` or somethink like that (short name max 5 character and so simple as possible) and paste the text the the new file, and save it!

Comment: ... Why do you think the user name is the issue